# How to calculate time and show in H-M with 12 hour clock, based on distance and speed using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, codeigniter

Hello i have a script in javascript that shows and calculates time based on distance and speed, but i don't want it to show only in minutes, for example if over 60 minutes i want it to show hours as well with 12 hour clock format if its less then 00:35. I am not very good at reading and writing javascript coding so i can't find where that timing area is set in this script and how do i change it to show hours + minutes. Thank You and hope i did not make this confusing. Sorry for any complications.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
//--------------Settings--------------------------------    
//ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code, use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO 3166-2_alpha-2#US
var countrycode="US"
//Rate per mil (2.00)
var ratepermi=2.00;
//Minimum fare (40)
var minimum_fare=50;
//Currrency Symbol
var currencysymbol="$";
//Avoid motorways / highways? true/false
var avoidHighways=false;
//Avoid toll roads? true/false
var avoidTolls=false;
//Show summary? true/false
var showsummary=false;
//Disclaimer text
var disclaimer="Please be aware this is only an estimated fare and the final price will be quoted on request"

var rateperminute=0.45;
var ratio=1.1; // Price will be 110% of the computed estimate

//----------End Settings--------------------------------    

function initialize() 
{
    var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: countrycode}};
    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('inputfrom'));
    var searchBoxfrom = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('inputto'));
    var searchBoxto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
}

function ftn_estimate()
{
    if (document.getElementById('inputfrom').value!="" && document.getElementById('inputto').value!="")
    {
        var origin = document.getElementById('inputfrom').value;
        var destination = document.getElementById('inputto').value;

        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
          {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
            avoidHighways: avoidHighways,
            avoidTolls: avoidTolls,
          }, callback); 
    }
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;

      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {

        if(showsummary)
        {
            document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML=origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]  + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '+ results[j].duration.text;
            document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML+="<br /><font color='red'>" + disclaimer + "</font>"
        }
        document.getElementById('distance').value=(results[j].distance.value/1609.34).toFixed(1);
        document.getElementById('time').value=(results[j].duration.value/60).toFixed(1);

        var calc_fare_dist=(results[j].distance.value/1609.34)*ratepermi;
        var calc_fare_time=(results[j].duration.value/60)*rateperminute;
        // Provided you want to add 0.35 per minute to the "per mile price"
        var calc_fare = (calc_fare_dist + calc_fare_time)*ratio;


        if (calc_fare<minimum_fare)
        {
            calc_fare=minimum_fare;
        }   
        document.getElementById('fare').value=currencysymbol+calc_fare.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<link href="../../../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<center>
      <div id="formbox">
        <h1 class="fare_title">FARE ESTIMATE</h1>
           <div class="div1">
              <span class="ride">Ride in Style</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"><span class="ride">Safe and Reliable</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"><span class="ride">Fully Licensed</span><img class="check_icon" src="../../../../check2.png" alt="check1"/>
               </div>
        <input id="inputfrom" type="text" placeholder="From" style="width:400px" class="inputform">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 16px; color: #3F3F3F; text-transform: uppercase;">to</h3>
        <input id="inputto" type="text" placeholder="To" style="width:400px;" class="inputto">
        <br/>
        <input type="button" onclick="ftn_estimate();" value="Estimate Fare" class="fare_button">
        <br/><br/>
        <table class="resultsbox">
            <tr><td class="time_style">Time (mins)</td><td><input id="time" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="distance_style">Distance (mi)</td><td><input id="distance" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="fare_style">Estimated Fare</td><td><input id="fare" readonly type="text" placeholder="--"></td></tr>
        </table>

        <span id="summary"></span>
    </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below steps:

1. read the value into a variable let's say x;
2. Get hours by dividing x by 60 i.e x/60;
3. Get minutes using modulus(%) operator i.e. x%60.
4. concatenate hours and minutes using : as connector.

   ```
   var timeInMins= results[j].duration.value; //Read your number of minutes here.
   var hour = parseInt(timeInMins/60);
   var minutes = timeInMins%60;
   var time = hour+":"+minutes;
   document.getElementById('time').value=time;
   ```

you have the final result cheers :)

Comment: Thank You Naresh Kumar for your respond. Where do i place the code you wrote above can you please show me how to do this, i am confused my friend. Thank You Again.

Comment: Hi Eden, you will have to replace below line with the code i had given earlier. document.getElementById('time').value=(results[j].duration.value/60).toFixed(1);

Comment: Now its showing something else i don't know if i put the reading minutes right in javascript language the calculator works but shows for example 67:30 so basically that is over an hour i cant get it to show 01:30:00, can you please check what i did wrong thank you so much for your help. https://jsfiddle.net/EdenG/03ow83y7/